# How to customize Input slider to make volume bar

Tags: javascript, css, input, range

I'm trying to make volume bar with input slider with styled-components.

I could find many useful information but cannot find about how to customize valued area.
For example, if I set volume as 80, default html input range color from 0 to 80 blue. I want to change this color but couldn't find any information about it. When I set `-webkit-appearance: none;` I could find it becomes transparent but I just want to change colors of it. (Not the background. I know I can do that with background).

edit) This is my code

```
const StyledTrackVolumeSlide = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  // -webkit-appearance: none; I know this code will reset default css
  background: #555;
  height: 0.25em;
  outline: none;
  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
```

I tried these properties, but could not find one with the blue valued background color. And also cannot find in chrome dev tools. Tried all the stuffs from [here](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)

```
&::-webkit-slider-thumb{
}

&:focus{

}

&::-ms-track{

}
```

Is there any possible way to customize input slider's valued color with plain CSS?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code as well here

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti I edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tool: https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler

Among other things it allows to style progress indication.

To make the slider vertical you'll have to use CSS transform, though.

Here is an example:

```js
for (let e of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"].slider-progress')) {
  e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value);
  e.style.setProperty('--min', e.min == '' ? '0' : e.min);
  e.style.setProperty('--max', e.max == '' ? '100' : e.max);
  e.addEventListener('input', () => e.style.setProperty('--value', e.value));
}
```

```css
/*generated with Input range slider CSS style generator (version 20201223)
https://toughengineer.github.io/demo/slider-styler*/
input[type=range].styled-slider {
  height: 2.2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*progress support*/
input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress {
  --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
  --ratio: calc((var(--value) - var(--min)) / var(--range));
  --sx: calc(0.5 * 2em + var(--ratio) * (100% - 2em));
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/*webkit*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  margin-top: calc(max((1em - 1px - 1px) * 0.5,0px) - 2em * 0.5);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
}
input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#007cf8,#007cf8) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #efefef;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#0061c3,#0061c3) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #e5e5e5;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#2f98f9,#2f98f9) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #f5f5f5;
}

/*mozilla*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-track {
  height: max(calc(1em - 1px - 1px),0px);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-moz-range-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-moz-range-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-moz-range-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#007cf8,#007cf8) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #efefef;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#0061c3,#0061c3) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #e5e5e5;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-moz-range-track {
  background: linear-gradient(#2f98f9,#2f98f9) 0/var(--sx) 100% no-repeat, #f5f5f5;
}

/*ms*/
input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-track {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb:hover {
  background: #0061c3;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:hover::-ms-track {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider::-ms-thumb:active {
  background: #2f98f9;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider:active::-ms-track {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: max(calc(1em - 1px - 1px),0px);
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
  margin: -1px 0 -1px -1px;
  background: #007cf8;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:hover::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #0061c3;
  border-color: #9a9a9a;
}

input[type=range].styled-slider.slider-progress:active::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2f98f9;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="styled-slider slider-progress" style="width: 25em;" />
<br />

<!--this div is needed to cut off all that's not needed, you have to specify width explicitly-->
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 2.2em; overflow: hidden;">
  <!--this div catches the size of the child block-->
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <!--this div sizes itself to the width of the <input> and makes itself square, also rotates contents-->
    <div style="display: inline-block; height: 0; padding: 0 0 100% 0; transform: rotate(-90deg);">
      <!--style <input> as usual as if it is horizontal-->
      <input type="range" class="styled-slider slider-progress" style="width: 10em;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
more content to the right of the vertical slider
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I think this is the most kind code generator for range css I can find. Thank you! @paul

Comment: @YuTaek, I'm glad you like it. 

Answer (score 1):

"default html input range color" doesn't exist, the element is rendered by your browser.

You must specify `-webkit-appearance: none;` (depends browser), for telling to the browser "don't design the input, I take care of that".
[another tutorial](https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html)

Sadly you must recreate input element, you can't just override color.

Comment: Thx I know what to do now then. It was so hard to find about it :/ Thanks again!